# Sequence of Focus method in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml

When I call to the Focus method to set the focus in another control of the UWP form, the LostFocus event of the current active control is called some time later.

For example:

```
MyControl.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard); 
SaveFormData();
```

The problem is that LostFocus is called after the SaveFormData(). The active control is a custom control where LostFocus is used to bind the control data with the data model.
In Win32, I would solve it using PostMessage function but I cannot find a similar thing in UWP.

Which is the sequence of Focus method()?  is it called asynchronously ?  maybe using the Dispatcher?  How can force LostFocus before to call SaveFormData()?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue before and I solved with this piece of code. This basically force a LostFocus on the control you pass to it.

```
void LoseFocus(Control control) {
    var isTabStop = control.IsTabStop;
    control.IsTabStop = false;
    control.IsEnabled = false;
    control.IsEnabled = true;
    control.IsTabStop = isTabStop;
}
```

The issue is exactly what you think, the Focus method do asynchronous operations. Another solution could be to use an async call with Dispatcher and put a little Delay before the SaveFormData call. Try out these methods.